# Why does .ToString("000.0000") give a Cannot find an overload error?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use `.ToString()` for formatting the numbers for example : if I have 4.44 after to string the number must be 004.4400. When I use `.ToString()` alone everything work perfect for example:

```
$B = 4.444
$C = $B.ToString("000.0000") -replace "," , "."
```

but when I try to use `.ToString()` in cycle everything goes wrong and I don't know why.

Here is my script:

```
$path = "C:\Users\georgi\Desktop\5\"
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\georgi\Desktop\5\" -PipelineVariable 'f' |
ForEach-Object{
  $Program_Name = "LH2113814_11111-300"
    $PrepareDate = (Get-Content -Path $f.FullName) | Select -Index 9
     $Date = $PrepareDate.Substring(31,4) + $PrepareDate.Substring(28,2)  + 
$PrepareDate.Substring(25,2) + $PrepareDate.Substring(36,8) 
   $A = (Get-Content -Path $f.FullName) | Select -Index 14
     $B = $A.Substring(43,5)
       $C = $B.ToString("000.0000") -replace ",","."
         $D = (Get-Content -Path $f.FullName) | Select -Index 20
           $E = $D.Substring(37,5)
             $F = "00" + $E + "0"
               $EXPORT = $Program_Name + $Date + $C + $F | Add-Content 
('C:\Users\georgi\Desktop\5\test.dat')
}
```

Error:

```
Cannot find an overload for "ToString" and the argument count: "1".
At line:8 char:12
+ $B.ToString("000.0000") -replace ".","," 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Comment: Did you attach a debugger and step through the code?

Comment: I did not attach debugger

Comment: Then start by doing that.

Comment: what error are u getting?

Comment: Cannot find an overload for "ToString" and the argument count: "1".
At line:8 char:12
+            $C = $B.ToString("000.0000") -replace ".",","
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Comment: Your indentation is very odd and makes the code hard to read. If you ever get this code working the way you want it to I highly recommend making your way over to CodeReview.SE to have this code evaluated. I see ... issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these lines:

```
 $B = $A.Substring(43,5)
   $C = $B.ToString("000.0000") -replace ",","."
```

`$B` is of type `String`. The [`ToString()` member function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tc6ws5s(v=vs.110).aspx) of that type does not accept any parameters, which is why it's complaining.

I can't tell based on what you've posted, but perhaps you need to cast that string to a `float` first:

```
 $B = [float]$A.Substring(43,5)
   $C = $B.ToString("000.0000") -replace ",","."
```

Comment: Than you very very very much